# Source Control - Pending Changes - Included/Excluded Changes - Can it be made taller?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm prepared to duck when the tomatoes are throw because this seems so simple.  Nevertheless...  In Visual Studio 2013 when looking at pending changes is there way to *vertically* expand the included changes and excluded changes segments ?

For example this morning I have a large changes set (around 1200 of the files pictured below are auto generated T4s, but it it's still tough to look over that much data in  300 pixels.

[image]

Comment: I haven't had this problem until I just ran vs2013 update 2. Now I have this issue!

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, still same quirky behavior as OP. Buggy as heck, or at least a poor algorithm. There is no reason why more lines should display in a smaller window :D If it's not fixed in 2022, I may submit a bug.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same behavior in VS2015.

You can avoid the tiny box by collapsing parts of the tree, it only appears when the currently shown list is "too long".

Comment: Thanks for this - was the issue I was experiencing also

Answer (score 3):

I had to select the View Options > Show Solution Changes  then the entire list was visible without scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's happened to me too:-). Wasn't the case here though. Seems to have been a bug that was patched at some point.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** 
On **VS 2015/Update 2**, the behavior is that the two scrollable sections appear when the *expanded height* exceeds a certain limit.  I.e., to make those sections disappear/merge into one, it seems to be enough to just collapse some of the tree nodes, so that the height falls below that magical limit.

*[Original post follows]*

Had the exact same issue (I'm running VS 2013 Pro, Update 4)

Found no UI options that would fix it.  So I decided to just "learn to live with it", and started making actual changes (i.e. include/exclude items, Undo, Compare, etc.) -- and suddenly noticed that it reverted back to that "tall view" on its own!  *And*, it's still in the "Tree View" mode:

[image]

I'm guessing it was the move of some of the items into 'Excluded Changes' section (which became empty for some reason -- it wasn't before). I didn't catch what *actually* did the trick, but that seems like the most likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to List View which will give you all the vertical space you could want, but obviously you lose the folder heirarchy, so it's not ideal :(

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) to enable Windows Explorer integration which uses the old style dialog which is completely resizable.

**EDIT**: Added image of list view.

[image]

Comment: Am I missing something? List view (which I use sometimes) sits in the same 300px box.

Comment: I'm VS2013 as well.  Mine doesn't change size - odd.

Comment: I've updated my post with a screenshot of it in action - note where the scrollbar is sitting. I'm on Windows 8.1 with VS2013 Ultimate v12.0.21005.1 REL - but I can't imagine any of that makes a difference. Wierd!!

Comment: OK - so I think i figured this out a bit.  My theory is that there was a bug fix with VS 2013 update 1.  At first the included changes area was 300px  list or nested.   I then was able to 'trigger' it moving full size.  I now have full size for both  folder & list !  You mind if I edit your answer and include the steps that did it for me before marking as answer ?

Comment: @RB. Would you share How you "trigger" it ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this under Visual Studio Update 4 and 5 and it seems that the current behavior is that if there are more than 99 items in either the "Included Changes" or in the "Excluded Changes" list, both lists are limited to 300 pixels.

This makes sense to me, as it would become too hard to switch between "Included Changes" and "Excluded Changes" otherwise, having to scroll back and forth (though making creative use of collapse would make it easier).

It would have been nice that when one docks the Pending Changes panel as a document, the included and excluded changes would show as 2 columns with infinite scrolling, but alas, this is not the case.

In some cases, switching to list view removes some of the "tree" nodes if you have folders in your set of changes. This may cause the panel to collapse with fewer changes.